# Counting the Vowels at the End of a Word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function named vowelEndings that takes a string, text, as a parameter.

The function vowelEndings returns a dictionary d in which the keys are all the vowels that are the last letter of some word in text. The letters a, e, i, o and u are vowels. No other letter is a vowel. The value corresponding to each key in d is a list of all the words ending with that vowel. No word should appear more than once in a given list. All of the letters in text are lower case.

The following is an example of correct output:

```
>>> t = 'today you are you there is no one alive who is you-er than you'
>>> vowelEndings(t)
{'u': ['you'], 'o': ['no', 'who'], 'e': ['are', 'there', 'one', 'alive']}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def vowelEndings(text):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    vowelCount = 0
    words = text.split()

    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            vowelCount += 1

    return vowelCount

t = 'today you are you there is no one alive who is you-er than you'
print(vowelEndings(t))
```

Output:

```
5
```

What is doing is counting the vowels of the beginning of each word but it should be counting the vowels of the end of each word. Also, it should print out the vowel and the word which the vowel is referring to like in the question. I need help with that.

Comment: What have you tried to check the end of the word instead of the beginning?  Have you made *any* attempt to build the desired dictionary to return?

Comment: You will need a dict where the values are sets. Getting the last letter of a word should be fairly easy, just do word[-1], which gives you the key in the result dict

Comment: I thought with what I have it would work and I have tried different things to make this program work but this is the closest I've gotten to make it work

Comment: `{v:[w for w in t.split() if w.endswith(v)] for v in 'aeiou'}` try that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. The missing aspects are:

- To extract the *last* letter, use `word[-1]`.
- You need to create a dictionary with vowel keys.
- The dictionary values should be `set` to avoid duplicates.

The classic Python solution is to use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

t = 'today you are you there is no one alive who is you-er than you'

def vowelEndings(text):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    d = defaultdict(set)

    for word in text.split():
        final = word[-1]
        if final in vowels:
            d[final].add(word)

    return d

print(vowelEndings(t))

defaultdict(set,
            {'e': {'alive', 'are', 'one', 'there'},
             'o': {'no', 'who'},
             'u': {'you'}})
```

Comment: I got it now. I totally forgot about set and word[-1]. Thank you that was a big help